# Strapi develop script not working with PM2

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, strapi

I am trying to run Strapi in development mode with pm2 by using this command:

```
pm2 start npm --name myprojectname -- run develop
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error

> ```
> 0|edtech-a | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
> 0|edtech-a |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dimit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> 0|edtech-a |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> ```

- PM2 version is 4.5.1
- NodeJS version is 14.15.4
- NPM version is 6.13.2
- Strapi version is 3.1.0-alpha.5

I get the same error when I try to run Strapi in development mode through an ecosystem.config.json file as well.

Has somebody faced this issue, if yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: When you run the project without pm2, is it working without any problem?

Comment: @HasipTimurtas yes I have no problems when I run it normally.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you run normally? when you try `npm run develop` it is working correctly yes?

Comment: I use yarn develop, but yes, it's working correctly.

Comment: ok, check my updated answer, run the command for yarn.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I encountered some problems myself and decided to go for a workaround:

Create a script with the commands you would type normally:

> touch strapi.sh

Type in your desired commands:

> nano strapi.sh

```
    cd my-strapi-project 
    npm run develop
```

Close and save (Crtl+x then type "y" and press enter).

Now just start that file with pm2

> pm2 start strapi.sh

Check if everything works fine

> pm2 logs

Thats it.

Comment: worked for me with the "You need to run strapi develop in a Strapi project. Make sure you are in the right directory" message

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this:

```sh
pm2 start npm --name myprojectname --interpreter bash -- run develop
```

**UPDATED**

for yarn

```
pm2 start yarn --name myprojectname --interpreter bash -- run develop
```

Comment: This is what I get now:

C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file
C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD: line 12: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''